# What US airports don't require removing CPAP for scanning at TSA?

Tags: usa, health, airport-security

I've gotten a number of different responses at airports.  Atlanta requires removing a [CPAP](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/specialneeds/cpap.shtm), but Reagan didn't.  Any others know what airports require/don't require it?  (And why its inconsistent)?

Comment: CPAP? Any chance you could define that?

Comment: From the TSA website: [Continuous Positive Airway Pressure](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/specialneeds/cpap.shtm) machine.

Comment: A [CPAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_airway_pressure) is a piece of medical equipment used to assist breathing in certain situations, such as certain complications of asthma or emphysema, or certain sleep breathing disorders like sleep apnea.

Comment: @ankur that's great -- post the link with a short summary and it would be the right answer.

Comment: @HedgeMadge: I think the intent of the OP's question is different, wants on-ground analysis of what happens at airports. I'm not qualified to give an answer on that.

Comment: Typically if someone needs information on a CPAP they know what it is.

Comment: FTR note that the link to the web site is not working...cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Speaking as someone who travels with someone who travels with a CPAP, the answer is: **it varies**.

The TSA gets a lot of crap, and (imo) much/most of it is deserved. But oddly enough, random checks *are* a reasonable security approach.

Traveling with a CPAP has improved immensely over the last few years. That's partly due to the equipment getting smaller & lighter, partly because more people have been diagnosed with sleep apnea (and so the TSA sees CPAPs more often), and partly due to TSA employees getting some training. It's been many years since the time I saw someone told they couldn't bring their CPAP on board "because it's scuba gear, and we don't allow pressurized containers on board."

The good news: as it's medically-required equipment, the TSA has ruled that it doesn't count against your carry on *or* personal bag quota. And if you happen to toss an extra extension cord (or a pair of socks?) in the bag, what are they going to do?

The two places where things can get weird are:

- Do you want/need to bring distilled water in your carry on bag?
  I think having a doctor's letter saying it's medically necessary helps.
- Do you want to try to use the CPAP while on board?
  If yes, does you have a battery, or will you need a power adapter?

Possibly useful resources:

- [TSA: Continuous Positive Airway Pressure (CPAP) Machine](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/specialneeds/cpap.shtm)
- [TSA: Travelers with Disabilities and Medical Conditions](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/specialneeds/index.shtm)
- [The TSA Blog: Traveling With a CPAP Machine](http://blog.tsa.gov/2011/02/traveling-with-cpap-machine.html) (February 2011)

Comment: First link is out of order